# How to manually stop model training by using on_batch_end callback

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

How can you stop training model early via callback `on_batch_end`? I've tried setting `model.stop_training` attribute to `True` but it does not seem to work.

Here is the code I use:

```
callback = LambdaCallback(on_batch_end=lambda batch,logs:self.on_batch_end(batch, logs))
self.model.fit(
          x=trainData,
          steps_per_epoch=stepsPerEpoch,
          epochs=epochs,
          verbose=verbose,
          callbacks=[callback])
```

And here is my on_batch_end method. Have in mind that I enter it numerous times and it never ends training procedure.

```
def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs):
    # grab the current learning rate and add log it to the list of
    # learning rates that we've tried
    lr = K.get_value(self.model.optimizer.lr)
    self.lrs.append(lr)

    # grab the loss at the end of this batch, increment the total
    # number of batches processed, compute the average average
    # loss, smooth it, and update the losses list with the
    # smoothed value
    l = logs["loss"]
    self.batchNum += 1
    self.avgLoss = (self.beta * self.avgLoss) + ((1 - self.beta) * l)
    smooth = self.avgLoss / (1 - (self.beta ** self.batchNum))
    self.losses.append(smooth)

    # compute the maximum loss stopping factor value
    stopLoss = self.stopFactor * self.bestLoss
    print("\n[INFO]: Comparing Smooth Loss {} and Stop Loss {}".format(smooth, stopLoss))
    # check to see whether the loss has grown too large
    if self.batchNum > 1 and smooth > stopLoss:
      # stop returning and return from the method
      print("[INFO]: Loss is too high. Stopping training!")
      self.model.stop_training = True
      return

    # check to see if the best loss should be updated
    if self.batchNum == 1 or smooth < self.bestLoss:
      self.bestLoss = smooth
      
    # increase the learning rate
    lr *= self.lrMult
    K.set_value(self.model.optimizer.lr, lr)
```

And here is output from training:

```
[INFO]: Loss is too high. Stopping training!
524/535 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 19639.2344 - binary_accuracy: 0.5551
[INFO]: Comparing Smooth Loss 10783.845046550889 and Stop Loss 2.7601591997381787
[INFO]: Loss is too high. Stopping training!
525/535 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 19726.4941 - binary_accuracy: 0.5555
[INFO]: Comparing Smooth Loss 10962.001075307371 and Stop Loss 2.7601591997381787
[INFO]: Loss is too high. Stopping training!

[INFO]: Comparing Smooth Loss 11144.855858488723 and Stop Loss 2.7601591997381787
[INFO]: Loss is too high. Stopping training!
527/535 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 20104.7402 - binary_accuracy: 0.5560
[INFO]: Comparing Smooth Loss 11329.031436631449 and Stop Loss 2.7601591997381787
[INFO]: Loss is too high. Stopping training!
```

Comment: can you try overriding the method on_batch_end as I did in my answer.

Comment: Sadly I cannot. You see, I am trying to implement Learning Rate Finder class and because of that I cannot inherent keras.callbacks.Callback.

Comment: Ohh I see. Sorry than I can't help you further just letting you know.

Comment: Its fine. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same question and it seems that keras will only interrupt training at the end of an epoch. If you set `self.model.stop_training = True` in your callback after a batch, the training will continue with the following batches until the end of the epoch and only stop then.

One solution that I've found is to reduce the length of an epoch with the option `step_per_epoch` in when calling `tf.keras.Model.fit`. With shorter epochs, you have a finer control with the stopping condition.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please elaborate Where were you setting `model.stop_training` attribute to `True`?

Here is a simple sample code which calls `on_batch_end` callback for stopping training early.

```
import tensorflow as tf
class myCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
  def on_batch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
    if(logs.get('accuracy')>0.99):
      print("\nReached 99% accuracy so cancelling training!")
      self.model.stop_training = True

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

callbacks = myCallback()

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=10, callbacks=[callbacks])
```

output

```
Epoch 1/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 0.1994 - accuracy: 0.9406
Epoch 2/10
1875/1875 [==============================] - 7s 4ms/step - loss: 0.0805 - accuracy: 0.9754
Epoch 3/10

Reached 99% accuracy so cancelling training!
1875/1875 [==============================] - 7s 3ms/step - loss: 0.0538 - accuracy: 0.9835
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7f2fb1a4e0b8>
```

you can checkout [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/Callback) for list of all callbacks you can use just change the method name you want to use.